# How can I pass form values from one page onto another?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I need to pass a URL and domain type from one HTML page to another and apparently the best way to do this is using java-script to create a cookie and pass the value to the next HTML page, but I do not know anything about cookies or even where to start. Where can I find a good guide to get me started with cookies and/or how to pass the value from one form to another? Is there a simpler way instead of using cookies? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one way to do this:
- You can pass the values using GET or POST variables.
- Save the value in the session (depending on the language this can be more or less easier).
- Or save it to a cookie.

I think the easiest way to do it is to use POST variables (is as easy as with GET but you should avoid passing an URL in the url itself).

Comment: Can I just use a link method to pass the values in the url? I also need to check the who is to make sure the url is not taken before I leave the page.